# How do I render two HTML pages using the same information in Flask?

Tags: html, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

In a dashboard() function in Flask, the user is given a search form to fill, and after filling the form, he gets the names of some books he searched for. On clicking the title of a book, he should be directed to an HTML page where he gets some information about the book.

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET','POST'])
def dashboard():
    form = SearchForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.ISBN.data:
            results = Books.query.filter(Books.ISBN.like('%' + form.ISBN.data + '%')).all()
        elif form.Title.data:
            results = Books.query.filter(Books.Title.like('%' + form.Title.data + '%')).all()
        return render_template('search_results.html', name=current_user.username, form = form, results=results)

    return render_template('dashboard.html', name=current_user.username, form = form)
```

In the above function, SearchForm is a WTF flask form.

This is the code in my search_results.html:

```
{% for result in results: %}
   {{result.ISBN}}
   <a href="{{url_for('details')}}">{{result.Title}}</a> 
{%endfor%}
```

And this is my details function:

```
@app.route('/dashboard/details', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def details():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('details.html')
    return render_template('details.html')
```

What I want is, to take the form data that the user filled in the dashboard() function, and use that data in the details() function to pass that information to the details.html page, where I will print the data that the user filled in, as well as the book's data stored in a database.
But I can't figure out how to do so.
I tried making the form global using `global form = SearchForm()`, but that gives me a syntax error:

```
global form = SearchForm()
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to 'url_for' function which are also known as url parameters, usually IDs are used. For example:

```
{{ url_for('details', book_id=res.id) }}
```

So then you will be able to get the passed arguments like:

```
@app.route('/dashboard/details/<int:book_id>')
def details(book_id):
```

But, if your titles are unique, and you query your data with them, you can totally use them as parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask session global variable to suit your purpose. Please refer to: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.session

This is a good tutorial with more detailed information on how to use flask `session` global variable:
https://www.javatpoint.com/flask-session

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data into the url_for function by just adding a comma and placing the data after the comma (like you do in render_template)
So what you would need to do is in your html

```
{{ url_for('details', book_id=res.id) }}
```

And this in your routes

```
@app.route('/dashboard/details/<int:book_id>')
def details(book_id):
```